# How to read a string from txt file using getline() and store into string variable?

Tags: c++, string, ifstream, getline

I have a `.txt` file with some info:

[image: img]

```
ifstream readfile(fileName);
if (readfile)
{
    readfile >> n;

    array = new Zakaz[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        readfile >> array[i].client.name;
        readfile >> array[i].client.tableNumber;
            
        getline(readfile, array[i].dish.nameOfDish);
        readfile >> array[i].client.fullDishQuantity;
        readfile >> array[i].dish.price;

        readfile >> array[i].time.hour;
        readfile >> array[i].time.minute;
    }
```

How can I read a full string with `getline()`?

Comment: what do you mean with "full string" ?

Comment: What is an "only string"?

Comment: I need to read "Milkshake and soda" into an array[i].dish.nameOfDish

Comment: `getline` does read a full line.

Comment: if it doesnt work as you expect please include a  [mcve] and input, output and expected output in the quesiton

Comment: No, it leaves an empty line